# What is the correct way to check for a '?' in a case statement

Tags: bash, escaping, case, glob

I have below bash script using `getopts`. My code works as expected, i.e.,when an invalid option is specified, $myopt variable is set to '?' character and the case statement currectly processes the code matching the '?'.
Else where I see similar code using '\?' instead of just '?' in the case statement (please see the last three commented lines of the code block).

Is there any specific reason why the'?' is escaped ? I am aware any charcter can be escaped using '\' but my code works perfectly fine without escaping the '?'.

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":abc" myopt; do
    case $myopt in
      [a-c])
       echo "$myopt is a valid option!" >&2
       ;;
      ?)
       echo "$OPTARG is an invalid option!" >&2
       ;;
     # \?)
     #  echo "$OPTARG is an invalid option!" >&2
     #  ;;
     esac
done
```

For the benefit of other reading this, below code will only work if '?' is escaped (see the accepted answer for a good explanation).

```
#!/bin/bash 
while getopts ":abc" myopt; do
    case $myopt in
      \?)
       echo "$OPTARG is an invalid option!" >&2
       ;;

   [a-c])
       echo "$myopt is a valid option!" >&2
       ;;
    esac
done
```

if the script file is myscript.sh it can be tested like this -

```
./myscript.sh -a -z -a
```

Comment: Another reason: Suppose you have one of your options require an argument: `getopts ":abcd:" myopt`. If the user fails to provide the argument, myopt contains `:` and that would be gobbled up by the `?)` branch and provide a misleading error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the Bash `case` statement the `?` is a wildcard matching any single character/digit.
If you escape it with `\?` it specifically is trying to match the `'?'` char.

The `case` will continue to find a match, so in this case if the variable isn't `[a-c]` (a, b or c) then it will match if it the variable is 1 char.

Comment: I understood now. The above code is working because of pattern matching for '?' is done last in the case statement. In this specific case the code will work whether '?' is escaped or not. If the pattern match for '?' is the first test in the case statement, it has to be escaped. If we dont escape it with a '\' ,  every single character value in the myopt variable matches the bash wildcard '?'.

Comment: Yes. It would be best to use `\?` to check for the OPTARG being invalid to be clear. If a single character got through that was not `'?'` then it would be invalidly processed with just `?`